# AngularJS ng-class not working in ng-repeat with $index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list created with ng-repeat that works for everything except for adding the ng-class on condition.

```
<div ng-repeat="glossary in glossarySections"
     class="alphabet"
     ng-click="glossaryGoToSection($index)"
     ng-class="{'selected',$index == $parent.glossarySection}">
    {{glossary.name}}
</div>
```

ng-click works, and it creates the DOM the way I expect it to, but it doesn't add the 'selected' class for the alphabet currently shown.

Is there something that I am missing in this syntax?

Comment: `{selected:$index==$parent.glossarySection}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error: replace `,` to `:`.

Modify to `ng-class="{'selected': $index == $parent.glossarySection}">`.

Answer (score 1):

`ngClass` receives a hash object: `class: condition`

So you should use colon for key/condition separation:

`ng-class="{selected: $index==$parent.glossarySection}"`